# A link not to the mobile broswer, but to the applications

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a link to some page (Instagram), when I click on the link, it takes me to the link and the username to that like in the mobile browser, what should I type in order to work it in Instagram application in the mobile? If it doesn't exist, it will go to play.google/instagram in the play store

This is the link but it's not what I want

```
blah.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.instagram.com/blahhhh"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would decompile the Instagram app and have a look at its manifest.  Check if there is an intent filter that you can make use of.  If not, there's really nothing you can do.  It is the Instagram app's job to receive the intent that you send to Android.

Comment: Thank you Nightly Nexus, I'll look for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try {
Intent LaunchIntent =
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivity(LaunchIntent); 
//Here you can add more information, such as the specific profile that you want to launch,    in Intent format 
 }

    catch (Exception myIntent) {
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, although I didn't fill anything but it took my directly to Instagram app, the question is in the note "Here you can add more information, such as the specific profile that you want to launch, in Intent format" should I put something there? I really don't know, I put the profile instead of myIntent, still didn't take me there!